# Twitter Kit Android - TwitterApiClient retweet does not work

Tags: android, rest, twitter, twitterkit, apiclient

In my app so far, I am displaying a tweet (my own for now) using the Twitter Kit for Android and have a Retweet button with which I am attempting to (go figure) retweet using the Twitter API Client.

Here are the links I referred to before this:

[1) Twitter REST APIs from Android](https://twittercommunity.com/t/how-to-retweet-tweet-in-twitter-kit-for-android/88206/)

[2) Twitter Community Discussion on Retweeting using the TwitterApiClient](https://twittercommunity.com/t/how-to-retweet-tweet-in-twitter-kit-for-android/88206/)

This is the code I'm using:

```
    val twApiClient: TwitterApiClient = TwitterCore.getInstance().apiClient
    tbTweet.setOnMenuItemClickListener {
        when (it.itemId) {
            R.id.item_retweet -> {
                val call: Call<Tweet> = twApiClient.statusesService.retweet(tweetID, true)
                Log.i("Retweet", if (call.isExecuted) "Successful" else "Failed")
            }
        }
        true
    }
```

I'm not getting any errors but when I go to my Profile Page on twitter, the retweet doesn't show up. The same problem has been stated in the 2nd link I provided, but no solution was given.

I also Log out the Execution Status. It comes as "Failed", so I know that the call `retweet()` isn't even executing. But why?

What is the problem and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, apparently the code above is incomplete. You have to call `execute()` on the call object that is returned from the `retweet(tweetId, true)` method. And then, you can call an `onCompleteListener` to see if your retweet was successful or not.